# Edittext in recyclerview not focusable when deteting item

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I created a Full Screen Dialogfragment for advanced search. It has a recycler view and a Spinner that adds elements to that recycler view. Every item has an EditText, an spinner and a close button on the top right side (sorry I have to choose another icon for the close button). Depending on the option I choose (some of the options are dates) on the spinner "Add filter" the Edittext of the item could have an DatepickerDialog attached to it or not.
My proble is.
in the method "addEditext" i set "viewHolder.texto.setFocusable(false);" so its only posible to set a Date in that Edittext but in "onBindviewHolder" i set "viewHolder.texto.setFocusable(true);" and it is not working, when i add a filter with a Date EditText, i deleted it and later add another kind of EdittText that Ediitext is not focusable.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Boarding_searchViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {


        viewHolder.texto.setText(lista_filtro.get(position).getTexto());
        viewHolder.texto.setOnClickListener(null);
        viewHolder.texto.setFocusable(true);
        viewHolder.texto.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                //setting data to array, when changed
                // this is a semplified example in the actual app i save the text
                // in  a .txt in the external storage
                lista_filtro.get(position).setTexto(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });


        addFilterText(viewHolder, position);
        addSpinner( viewHolder, position);
        addCloseButton(viewHolder, position);

       // EditText aux= new EditText(viewHolder.itemView.getContext());
       // lista_textos.add(aux);
        //viewHolder.texto=lista_textos.get(position);
       addEditText(viewHolder, position);

    }


private void addEditText(final Boarding_searchViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {


        Date fecha= new Date();
     switch(lista_filtro.get(position).getFilter())
     {

         case ETD:
         case ETA:
         case AUTHORIZED_DATE:
             viewHolder.texto.setFocusable(false);
             final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

             final Cambiafecha cambiarfecha= new Cambiafecha(fecha, viewHolder.texto);


             viewHolder.texto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     new DatePickerDialog(viewHolder.itemView.getContext(), cambiarfecha, myCalendar
                             .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                             myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                 }
             });
             break;

     }

    }


class Cambiafecha implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    Date fecha;
    EditText texto;
    public Cambiafecha(Date fecha, EditText texto)
    {
        super();
        this.texto=texto;
        this.fecha=fecha;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {


        fecha.setMonth(month);
        fecha.setDate(day);
        fecha.setYear(year);
        updateLabel();
    }

    private void updateLabel() {

        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        texto.setText(sdf.format(fecha));
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the `RecycleView` is that it recycles `ViewHolders` as soon as they are not needed anymore. This improves overall performance. The drawback is that you have to ***"reset"*** a state of the `ViewHolder` on each `onBindViewHolder` call, because otherwise this recycled `ViewHolder` will contain a data from a previous binding(and `OnClickListeners` too).

The first step is to clear previous state of the `ViewHolder`, something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Boarding_searchViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
    viewHolder.texto.setText(null);
    ... //Rest of your code
}
```

However, it will clear all the data previously entered by user. So, you have to implement a temporary storage for all data. You already have `Filtro_boarding` item, this one should have a state.
Let’s say:

```
class Filtro_boarding{
    //your code here
    String state;
}
```

Then, you will have to change:

```
viewHolder.texto.setText(null);
```

to

```
viewHolder.texto.setText(lista_filtro.get(position).state);
```

Yet, you will have to add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` in order to listen for state changes.
I would change the `Boarding_searchViewHolder` to:

```
public static class Boarding_searchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements TextWatcher {

public Spinner spinner;
public EditText texto;
public TextView filtro;
public ImageButton cerrar;

private Filtro_boarding filter;

public Boarding_searchViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);

    filtro = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filtro);
    spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    texto = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.texto);
    cerrar = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.boton);

    texto.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

void bind(Filtro_boarding filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence, final int i, final int i1, final int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence, final int i, final int i1, final int i2) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
    if (filter != null) {
        if (editable != null) {
            filter.status = editable.toString();
        } else {
            filter.status = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Don't forget to call `viewHolder.bind(lista_filtro.get(position))` in your `onBindViewHolder` method.

Comment: @Tico1993 I've modified answer in order to provide some insights how you can implement it. Switching to ListView requires the same approach.

Comment: what about the OnClickListeners event i set to the edittext, would I change? The other problem i have is that when i delete an item, the item that takes the position of the item i just deleted also takes the event I set on the deleted item

Comment: @Tico1993 Yes, you are right. You should also call `viewHolder.texto.setOnClickListener(null);` in your `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: One more thing in the method "addEditext" i set  "viewHolder.texto.setFocusable(false);" so its only posible to set a Date in that Edittext but in "onBindviewHolder" i set "viewHolder.texto.setFocusable(true);" and it is not working, when i add a filter with a Date EditText, i deleted it and later add another kind of EdittText that Ediitext is not focusable. I update mi code in my question above.